# Android Google Navigations app: can I edit the source code?

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I want to add some small modifications to the Google Navigation app for Android. Is there open-source code for it that I could modify and recompile?

Comment: no it is not open source

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Navigation` is part of `Google Maps` and is not open source. So, no, you cannot do much about this, beside reverse engineering if you really in need. Or licensing GMaps (if possible, not sure).

Answer (score 2):

> Is there open-source code for it that I could modify and recompile?

No, sorry, Google Maps is not open source, which includes its Google Navigation component.